# Relationship between central divisor pairs

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Define *Central Divisors* as a pair of natural numbers (a,b), a $<=$ b, that are
closer (in the Euclidean distance sense) to their geometric mean $\sqrt{ab}$ than
any other divisors of the product ab.  For example, (18,20) are central
divisors, but (6,74) are not.  The values of a are OEIS A033676 for n = ab.
I've noticed the following behavior:

Proposition.  If

$$\sqrt{a} > \sqrt{b} - 1,$$

then (a,b) are central divisors.  The inequality is a sufficient, but not
necessary, condition for central divisors, as seen with (12,37).

The inequality is equivalent to

$$a > \left(-1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\sqrt{ab}}\right)^2/4$$

I've tested this numerically without exception, but of course that's not a
proof.  My question is: How can the above proposition be proven?

Comment: FYI, a somewhat related article is [On integers with many small prime factors](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1973__26_3_319_0.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the correct answer based on the hint by @DanielFischer, including
intermediate steps.  Let *a*,*b*,*c*,*d* be natural numbers such that *ab* = *cd*
and

$$a < c \le d < b;\tag{1}$$

that is, (*a*,*b*) are not Central Divisors according to the definition in the
original posting.  Then *b* > *d* and *c* > *a*, so

$$b + c > d + a$$

$$b - a > d - c$$

$$(b - a)^2 > (d - c)^2\tag{2}$$

Since 4*ab* = 4*cd*, we have

$$(b + a)^2 - (b - a)^2 = (d + c)^2 - (d - c)^2\tag{3}$$

From (2) and (3), it follows that

$$(b + a)^2 - (b - a)^2 + (b - a)^2 > (d + c)^2 - (d - c)^2 + (d - c)^2$$

$$(b + a)^2 > (d + c)^2$$

$$b + a > d + c$$

$$d + c \le b + a - 1\tag{4}$$

Assume

$$\sqrt{a} > \sqrt{b} - 1$$

Then

$$\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a} < 1$$

Squaring both sides, we have

$$b - 2\sqrt{ab} + a < 1$$

$$b + a - 1 < 2\sqrt{ab}$$

By (4),

$$d + c < 2\sqrt{ab} = 2\sqrt{cd}$$

$$d - 2\sqrt{cd} + c < 0$$

$$(\sqrt{d} - \sqrt{c})^2 < 0,$$

a contradiction.  Therefore, there are no solutions for *c* and *d* satisfying
(1), and (*a*,*b*) are Central Divisors according to the definition in the
original posting.

Answer (score 0):

I gave some more thought to the question above and believe I have found the
answer.  From the definition above, (*a*,*b*) are central divisors iff *ab* is not
the product of two factors both of which are smaller than *b*.  If *b* is prime,
then the proposition holds trivially for *all* values of *a* $\le$ *b* since
the multiples of *b* up to $b^2$ cannot be created from two factors both smaller
than *b*.  For composite *b* $\le$ 10, the proposition can be seen to hold by
inspection.

Otherwise, write the inequality from the original post as

$$(\sqrt{b} - 1)^2 \lt a \le b$$

Let *b* $\ge$ 12 be composite and let *k* be a proper divisor of *b*.  Then we can
write

$$ab = (ka)(b/k)$$

Assuming both factors on the right are less than *b*, we have

$$ka \lt b$$ and $$b/k \lt b$$

The latter inequality is always true since *k* $\ge$ 2, so the assumption is
equivalent to

$$ka \lt b$$ and $$ka \ge 2a$$

We have

$$b \gt (2 + \sqrt{2})^2 = 11.66$$

$$\sqrt{b} \gt 2 + \sqrt{2}$$

This is a solution to the following quadratic inequality:

$$(\sqrt{b})^2 - 4\sqrt{b} + 2 \gt 0$$

$$2b - 4\sqrt{b} + 2 \gt b$$

$$2(\sqrt{b} - 1)^2 \gt b$$

Then

$$ka \ge 2a \gt 2(\sqrt{b} - 1)^2 \gt b,$$

which is a contradiction to the previous assumption that *ka* $\lt$ *b*.  Therefore, *ab* cannot be the
product of two factors both less than *b*, QED.

Comment: I realized today that the above answer is incorrect because it assumes that the
smaller of the alternate factors of *ab* is an integer multiple (*k*) of *a*,
rather than a more general rational multiple (say *k/m*) of *a*, where *m* |
*a*.  I'm going to think about this some more.

Comment: A hint: If $n = ab$, then also $$n = \biggl(\frac{b+a}{2}\biggr)^2 - \biggl(\frac{b-a}{2}\biggr)^2\,.$$ And if $n = cd$ with $a < c \leqslant d < b$, then $d + c < b + a$. Now show that $\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a} < 1$ makes it impossible that $c$ and $d$ are integers. If you don't find a proof yourself (with or without that hint), I can post an answer giving the details. Just ping me with  request.

Comment: Great hint, thanks!  It's just what I needed.  I'll post what I came up with later today.

Comment: There seems to be a corollary:

If (*a*,*b*) are Central Divisors, then so are (*n*,*ab*) for all *n* such that

$$(a - 1)(b - 1) \lt n \le ab.$$

@DanielFischer, any thoughts on that one?

Answer (score 0):

As an example you give $(12,37)$, but we don't have $\sqrt{12}>\sqrt{37}-1$!

Let us note $n=ab$ where $a\leq b$. So we have $b=n/a$.

It is easy to see that
\begin{equation}
a+b\geq 2\sqrt{n}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Now let us suppose that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{a}>\sqrt{b}-1 
&\Longleftrightarrow &\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}<1\\
&\Longleftrightarrow & b-2\sqrt{ab}+a<1\\
&\Longleftrightarrow & b-2\sqrt{n}+a<1\\
&\Longleftrightarrow & b+a<2\sqrt{n}+1 \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
By combining (1) and (2), we conclude that
$$
2\sqrt{n}\leq a+b<2\sqrt{n}+1
$$.

In other terms $a+b=a+n/a$ is the smallest integer greater or equal than $2\sqrt{n}$ which proves that $(a,b)$ are central divisors.

Comment: $b + a < 2\sqrt{n} + 1$ does not in general imply $b + a \leq 2\sqrt{n}$, only when $n$is a perfect square.

Comment: Thanks, I will review my answer