# Seeking a proof of a general result on central divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Define the central divisors $\mathbf{CD}$(*N*) of a natural number *N* as paired
factors of *N* that are closer together than any of its other factor pairs.
More formally,

$$\mathbf{CD}(N) = (a,N/a),\text{ where }a = \text{max } \{x \in \mathbb{N}\ :\ x|N\text{ and }x \le \sqrt{N}\}$$

I wish to prove:

$$\text{If }\mathbf{CD}(N) = (a,b),\text{ then }\mathbf{CD}(mN) = (m,N)\text{ for }(a - 1)(b - 1)
\lt m \le N\tag{1}$$

This is a more general case of the proposition proved in a
[previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785418) that

$$\mathbf{CD}(mN) = (m,N)\text{ for }(\sqrt{ab} - 1)^2 \lt m \le N$$

since

$$( (\sqrt{ab} - 1)^2, ab ] \subseteq ( (a - 1)(b - 1), ab ]$$

from

$$(\sqrt{ab} - 1)^2 \ge (a - 1)(b - 1)$$

In (1), if *a* is 1, then *N* is a prime *p* and it follows that (*m*,*p*) are central
divisors as long as *m* $\le$ *p* since it's impossible to create the product
*mp* from two factors both smaller than *p*.  Without loss of generality, we may
therefore take 2 $\le$ *a* $\le$ *b*.

The lower limit on *m* is minimal and is a requirement since if
*m* = (*a* - 1)(*b* - 1), it's easily seen that (*m*,*N*) are not central
divisors:

$$m = (a - 1)(b - 1) \lt (a - 1)b \le a(b - 1) \lt ab = N$$

$$\mathbf{CD}(mN) = ((a - 1)b,a(b - 1))$$

The condition $\mathbf{CD}$(*N*) = (*a*,*b*) is also a requirement, as can be
seen by the counterexample *a* = 2, *b* = 6, *m* = 6, in which

$$m > (a - 1)(b - 1) = 5,$$

but (*m*,*N*) = (6,12) are not central divisors.

There are some obvious results if *a* or *b* is a prime, but I would like to
see a proof in the general case.  I have not been able to make progress without
resorting to manipulating the prime factorization of *mab*, so I am hoping there's
a simpler or more direct approach.

Comment: The inequality for *m* can be generalized to

$$(a-1)(b-1) \lt m \lt (a+1)(b+1).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by \eqref{1} the inequality

$$(a-1)(b-1) \lt m \lt (a+1)(b+1)\tag{1}\label{1}$$

First, if the product *ab* is a prime *p*, then its central divisors are {1,*p*} and
we have

$$1 \le m \le 2p + 1$$

It's straightforward to show that {*m*,*p*} are central divisors by considering the
possible factors of *mp*.

Otherwise, note that if \eqref{1} holds for central divisors *a* and *b*, then it also
holds for any other factor pair of *ab*.  This is also straightforward to show.

Next, let *w,x,y,z* be natural numbers with

$$(w-1)(x-1) \lt yz \lt (w+1)(x+1)\tag{2}\label{2}$$

Then

$$(y-x)(z-w) \le 0\tag{3}\label{3}$$

This can be shown by a proof by contradiction.

For {*m*,*ab*} to be central divisors, we must have

$$(m-ab)^2 \le (k-mab/k)^2\tag{4}\label{4}$$

for all divisors *k* of the product *mab*.  Each such divisor can be written as
$k = ij$, where *i* is a divisor of *m* and *j* is a divisor of *ab*.  It follows
that \eqref{1} holds for *i* and *j*:

$$(j-1)(ab/j-1) \lt i(m/i) \lt (j+1)(ab/j+1)$$

Applying \eqref{2} with *w* = *j*, *x* = *ab/j*, *y* = *i* and *z* = *m/i*, \eqref{3} can be written

$$(i-ab/j)(m/i-j) \le 0,$$

which reduces to \eqref{4}, QED.